# Крестики-нолики, помогите пожалуйста найти логическую ошибку

Tags: python, ооп, классы, разработка-игр, pygame

**main.py**:

```
import pygame

# Константы игры
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 300, 300
ROWS, COLS = 3, 3
SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH // COLS

# Цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Крестики-нолики')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.board = [['' for _ in range(COLS)] for _ in range(ROWS)]
        self.current_player = 'X'

        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 100)

    def draw_board(self):
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(COLS):
                pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, BLACK, (col * SQUARE_SIZE, row * SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE), 1)
                if self.board[row][col]:
                    text = self.font.render(self.board[row][col], True, BLACK)
                    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=((col * SQUARE_SIZE) + SQUARE_SIZE // 2, (row * SQUARE_SIZE) + SQUARE_SIZE // 2))
                    self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)

    def process_click(self, pos):
        row = pos[1] // SQUARE_SIZE
        col = pos[0] // SQUARE_SIZE
        if self.board[row][col] == '':
            self.board[row][col] = self.current_player
        if self.current_player == 'X':
            self.current_player = 'O'
        else:
            self.current_player = 'X'

    def check_winner(self):
        # Проверка строк
        for row in range(ROWS):
            if self.board[row][0] == self.board[row][1] == self.board[row][2] != '':
                return self.board[row][0]

        # Проверка столбцов
        for col in range(COLS):
            if self.board[0][col] == self.board[1][col] == self.board[2][col] != '':

        # Проверка диагоналей
        if self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][2] != '':
             return self.board[0][0]

        if self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][0] != '':
            return self.board[0][2]

        return None

def draw_winner(self, winner):
    text = self.font.render(f'Победитель: {winner}', True, BLACK)
text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2))
self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)

def run(self):
    running = True
game_over = False

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        else:
            event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            self.process_click(pos)
            self.draw_board()
if not game_over:
    winner = self.check_winner()
if winner:
    self.draw_winner(winner)
    game_over = True

pygame.display.flip()
self.clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = TicTacToe()
    game.run()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, правильно отформатируйте ваш код и лучше расскажите, что вы делаете, и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Если вопрос решен, вы можете принять ответ, для этого нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я попробовал отформатировать ваш код и кое-что подправить. Но вам еще есть над чем поработать.

```
import pygame

# Константы игры
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 300, 300
ROWS, COLS = 3, 3
SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH // COLS

# Цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
Fuchsia = (255, 0, 255)                                                # +++

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        pygame.init()
        
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Крестики-нолики')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.board = [['' for _ in range(COLS)] for _ in range(ROWS)]
        self.current_player = 'X'

        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 100)
# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
        self.draw_board()                                                 # +++

    def draw_board(self):
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(COLS):
                pygame.draw.rect(
                    self.screen, BLACK, (
                        col * SQUARE_SIZE, row * SQUARE_SIZE, 
                        SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE
                    ), 1)
                if self.board[row][col]:
                    text = self.font.render(self.board[row][col], True, BLACK)
                    text_rect = text.get_rect(
                        center=(
                            (col * SQUARE_SIZE) + SQUARE_SIZE // 2, 
                            (row * SQUARE_SIZE) + SQUARE_SIZE // 2
                        ))
                    self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)

    def process_click(self, pos):
        row = pos[1] // SQUARE_SIZE
        col = pos[0] // SQUARE_SIZE
        if self.board[row][col] == '':
            self.board[row][col] = self.current_player
        if self.current_player == 'X':
            self.current_player = 'O'
        else:
            self.current_player = 'X'

    def check_winner(self):
        # Проверка строк
        for row in range(ROWS):
            if self.board[row][0] == self.board[row][1] == self.board[row][2] != '':
                return self.board[row][0]

        # Проверка столбцов
        for col in range(COLS):
            if self.board[0][col] == self.board[1][col] == self.board[2][col] != '':
                pass
                return self.board[0][col]
                
        # Проверка диагоналей
        if self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][2] != '':
            return self.board[0][0]
        if self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][0] != '':
            return self.board[0][2]

        return None

    def draw_winner(self, winner):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)                                # +++
# ----> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 vvvvvvv <-----------        
        text = self.font.render(f'Победитель: {winner}', True, Fuchsia)
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2))
        self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)

    def run(self):
        running = True
        game_over = False           

        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
# -------------> vvvvv <--------------------------------------------------------------                     
#                else:                                                       # !!! ---
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over: # !!! +++
                
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    self.process_click(pos)
                    self.draw_board()
      
            if not game_over:
                winner = self.check_winner()
            if winner:
                self.draw_winner(winner)
                game_over = True

            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(60)

        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = TicTacToe()
    game.run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]